# Angularjs and codeigniter login process

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, authentication, crud

I'm doing a use authentication process but I got 500 External error. when I press submit. data is posted by angular I can see that in network.
please check the code and please tell me where is my code have error.

```js
 var app = angular.module('loginApp', []);
      app.controller('loginController', function($scope, $http) {
        console.log('controller ready');
        $scope.loginData = function(){
          $http.post('<?php echo site_url('index.php/user_authentication/login');?>',
          {
            'username':$scope.username,
            'password':$scope.password, 
          }).success(function() {console.log($scope.username, $scope.password);});
        }
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">


      <title>Bootstrap Material</title>

      <!-- Material Design fonts -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" type="text/css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

      <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');?>">

      <!-- Bootstrap Material Design -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/bootstrap-material-design.css');?>">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/ripples.min.css');?>">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/snackbar.min.css');?>">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <style type="text/css">
          html,body{
           height:100%;
            background-image: url('<?php echo base_url("assets/img/login.jpg"); ?>');
            background-size: cover;
          }
          .login-wrap, .register-wrap{
           
          }
          .well{margin-top: 30%; background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.8) !important;}
          legend{color:white !important;}
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid login-wrap" ng-app="loginApp" ng-controller="loginController">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
          <?php //username/password error
            echo "<div class='error_msg alert text-center'>"; 
            if (isset($error_message)) {
              echo '<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>';
                      echo $error_message;
                      echo'<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="alert-link">Change a few things up</a> and try submitting again.
                    </div>';
            }
            echo "</div>";
            ?>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            
            <div class="well bs-component">
              <form class="form form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                  <legend>Login</legend>
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="form-group label-floating has-warning">
                        <label class="control-label" for="username">Username</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="username" ng-model="username" type="text">
                      </div><!-- form-group -->

                      <div class="form-group label-floating has-warning">
                        <label class="control-label" for="username">Password</label>
                        <input class="form-control" id="username" ng-model="password" type="password">
                      </div><!-- form-group -->

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-raised col-md-12" ng-click="loginData()">Sign In</button>
                        <a href="#" class="text-warning">Forgot Password?</a>
                        <a href="#register" class="text-primary pull-right">Don't have a account?</a>
                      </div><!-- form-group -->

                    </div><!-- col-md-12 -->
                </fieldset>
              </form>
            </div><!-- well -->
          </div><!-- col-md-6 -->
        </div><!-- container -->
      </div><!-- row -->
    </div><!-- container-fluid -->

    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js');?>" ></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js');?>" ></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/ripples.min.js');?>" ></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/material.min.js');?>" ></script>
    <script src="<?php echo base_url('assets/js/snackbar.min.js');?>" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">$.material.init();</script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
    
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Controller

```
<?php 
class User_authentication extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        // Load form helper library
        $this->load->helper('form');

        // Load form validation library
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        // Load session library
        $this->load->library('session');

        // Load database
        //$this->load->model('login_database');
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('user_login');
    }

    public function login(){
        header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $data = array(
            'username' => $_POST['username'],
            'password' => $_POST['password'],
            );
        $this->load->model('user_login_model');
        $result = $this->user_login_model->login($data);

        if($result == TRUE){
            $this->load->view('test');
        } else {
            $this->load->view('404');
        }

    }
}
```

?>

Model

```
<?php 
class User_login_model extends CI_Model{
    public function login($data){
        $condition = "username =" . "'" . $data['username'] . "' AND " . "password =" . "'" . $data['password'] . "'";
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('user_login');
        $this->db->where($condition);
        $this->db->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

?>

URL,database is included in autoload.